# I want to Remove the addition symbol from in-between the numbers using python and please find the below my code

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
limit = int(input("Limit: "))
allvalue = ""
count = 0
number = 0


while count < limit:
    number += 1
    count += number 
    allvalue += str(number) + " + "

print(allvalue)
```

This is my output **1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 +**

I want the + symbol only in between the numbers.Not to be in the last or the first.

Comment: When I run your code, I enter `9` for `limit` and then I get the output as `1 2 3 4`. There are no `+` symbols, so I don't understand what your question is.

Comment: My Bad. I have edited the code. Now try to run again and you will find the issue

Comment: So you don't want the `+` after the `9`, right? Then you should stop your loop one number sooner and treat the last one specially after the loop.

Answer (score 1):

A likely solution is using `" + ".join()`, which uses the string method on the `" + "` to collect the values together

```py
>>> values = "1 2 3 4 5".split()
>>> " + ".join(values)
'1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
limit = int(input("Limit: "))
allvalue = ""
count = 0
number = 0
while count < limit:
    number += 1
    count += number
    if count != limit:
        allvalue += str(number) + " + "  
    else:
        allvalue += str(number)

print(allvalue)
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share with you a sure shot mathematical solution to this problem.

> This problem is a typical variation of `Sum of n numbers` problem, where the `sum` depicting `limit` here is already given as input, instead of `n`.

```
import math

limit = int(input("Limit: "))                          # n * (n + 1) / 2 >= limit
n = math.ceil( ((1 + 4*2*limit)**0.5 - 1) / 2 )        # ((b^2 - 4ac)^(1/2) - b) / 2a where a = b = 1, c = 2*limit

allValue = " + ".join([str(i) for i in range(1, n+1)])
print(allValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need both the `number` and `count` variables, and by starting from initial value you can add the `+` before the number.

```
limit = int(input("Limit: "))
count = 1
allvalue = str(count)
while count < limit:
    count += 1
    allvalue +=  " + " + str(count)
    
print(allvalue)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try using a for loop.

```
limit = int(input("Limit: "))
allvalue = ""

for i in range(0, limit):
   if i+1 == limit:
       allvalue += str(i+1)
   else:
       allvalue += str(i+1) + "+"

print(allvalue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is  simple and easy approach, you can try slice in the result string

```
print(allvalue[:-2])
```

code:

```
limit = int(input("Limit: "))
allvalue = ""
count = 0
number = 0


while count < limit:
    number += 1
    count += number 
    allvalue += str(number) + " + "

print(allvalue)
print(allvalue[:-2])
```

output:
result shared : https://onlinegdb.com/HFC2Hv4wq

```
Limit: 9
1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 
1 + 2 + 3 + 4
```